# How can I create a BackgroundService to run in a .NET MAUI App for Windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, maui

I am trying to create a `BackgroundService` in my .NET MAUI app that will listen for TCP connections while the app is continuously running.

I have tried to create this `BackgroundService` as I usually would via an `AddHostedService<>()` dependency injection in `MauiProgram.cs`, however, it doesn't appear to ever be starting the service during operation.

My service looks like this so far (it's just debug messages to verify that its running):

```
class TcpListenerService : BackgroundService
{
    readonly ILogger<TcpListenerService> _logger;

    public TcpListenerService(ILogger<TcpListenerService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Listener running at: {time}", DateTime.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am registering it like this:
`builder.Services.AddHostedService<Services.TcpListenerService>();`

There is no output to console via those logger messages. Is there something I am doing wrong? Or is something funky going on with MAUI? The app is currently targeting windows only.

Comment: Isn't MAUI a client application? Background services are automatically started by the ASP.NET Core infrastructure... on the server. Is your `TcpListenerService` on the server?

Comment: @Steven he is trying to do a simple worker thread.

Comment: The service is terminating because of an exception.  You can check event viewer to see the error.

Comment: @jdweng I've loaded the event viewer but am not too sure what I should be looking for. Is there an easy way to view this exception error if its happening?

Comment: Just by the time the service stopped.  Probably the error occurred when you started the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background Service seem to have been removed from MAUI for several reasons. Especially for this reason according to [Eric Erhardt](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41860#issuecomment-1144217170)

> Extensions.Hosting's main concept is its "Hosted Services" or
> BackgroundService. While this is definitely a useful concept in a
> client application, the abstraction isn't correct for client apps.
> Hosted Services get "Start" and "Stop". But what if the app is getting
> deactivated? Can the service tell the difference between that and the
> app being closed? Should all the Hosted Services get resumed when the
> app is resumed? These are all scenarios that would need to work and
> the Hosted Service abstraction isn't designed for these scenarios.
> Maui apps that need background service functionality need to use
> something that is designed for client apps.

You can find the full discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4393)

Their suggestion is to use [Shiny](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny)